# How to get direct link of videos files with Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I want to access direct links to videos of my users. they have PRO or above. also, the access token of each user includes the `video_files` scope but I still not able to see the `download` and `files` fields of their videos. 
I have now a PRO account and my users have Pro too.
How do I fix the issue, please? I bought a Pro account only for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can only get the direct file links and download metadata for videos on your own account.